# Возвращение экземпляром самого себя

Tags: ооп, pascal, freepascal

Может ли в функции класса, экземпляр возвращать сам себя. И как это реализовать, т.е. например

```
 function  vector.rot(a:single=0):vector;
 begin
  a:=a*pi/180;
  rot:=vector.create(x*cos(a)-y*sin(a),x*sin(a)+y*cos(a));  
 end;
```

Как сделать, чтобы не создавался новый экземпляр класса с изменёнными параметрами относительно базового (входного), а вместо этого менялись бы параметры входного экземпляра (как параметры менять я знаю) и он бы возвращался функцией.

Comment: Я ни жуя не понял. Вернуть `Self`? По-моему, уже пора почитать что-нибудь про ООП и множество вопросов отпадут сами собой.

Comment: так  ни в одной книжке не написано о реализациях в delphi/free pascal. в двух по крайней мере книгах ,есть главы "основы ООП" но там про self и как например перегрузить деструтор даже не упоминается .

Comment: Очевидно, если в книге "забыли" упомянуть про `Self`, то эту книгу надо в печку и взять другую :-) К сожалению, ничего насоветовать не могу, обучался ООП очень давно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function  vector.rot(a:single=0):vector;
var x1,y1: Integer;
begin
      a:=a*pi/180;
      x1:=x*cos(a)-y*sin(a);
      y1:=x*sin(a)+y*cos(a);
      x:=x1;
      y:=y1;
      rot:=Self;  
end;
```